# Using a double for loop to create nested divs in Jade

Tags: html, loops, for-loop, nested, pug

I currently have this piece of code in Jade that is suppose to generate a table of cells. My goal is to have n rows of divs each with m divs inside them that are aligned horizontally and equally spaced.

```
    div#grid
        - for (var row = 1; row <= height; row++) {
            div(class='row_#{row}')
            - for (var col = 1; col <= width; col++) {
                div(class='square seat#{row}_#{col}') 
            - }
        - }
```

I want my outcome to be like this

```
<div id="grid">
   <div class="row_1">
        <div class="square seat1_1"> </div>
        <div class="square seat1_2"> </div>
        <div class="square seat1_3"> </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row_2"></div>
       <div class="square seat2_1"> </div>
       <div class="square seat2_2"> </div>
       <div class="square seat2_3"> </div>
   </div>
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

However it is coming out like this

```
<div id="grid">
     <div class="row_1"></div>
     <div class="square seat1_1"> </div>
     <div class="square seat1_2"> </div>
     <div class="square seat1_3"> </div>
     <div class="row_2"></div>
     <div class="square seat2_1"> 
     </div><div class="square seat2_2"> </div>
     <div class="square seat2_3"> </div>
     .
     .
     .
 </div>
```

I was pretty sure this was going to work because of the indentation, but it isn't. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this to produce the outcome I want?

Answer (score 0):

Give your nested `for` loop an extra indent to have it rendered *inside* of that nested div

```
#grid
    - for (var row = 1; row <= height; row++)
        div(class='row_#{row}')
            - for (var col = 1; col <= width; col++)
                div(class='square seat#{row}_#{col}')
```

Ps: you don't necessarily need the curly braces with indents